# Divided Power Structure on Homology

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ be a commutative local noetherian ring. Let $X$ be a Tate resolution of $k$ with filtration $X^0\subseteq X^1\subseteq \ldots $, i.e., $X^n=$the algebra obtained by adjoining variables of degrees $0,1,\ldots,n$.

When does $H(X^n)$ inherit the divided power algebra structure of $X^n$?  That is, is it always the case that $\partial(x)^{(m)}\in B(X^n)$ for any $x\in X^n$ of positive even degree and $m\geq 1$? Or do we need to add assumptions about $X$ (for example, if $X$ is an acyclic closure (in which case it's a minimal resolution), then I believe this holds)?

Any answers or sources that you could recommend who be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!